# how to put timeout on jquery mobile dialog?

Tags: jquery, mobile, dialog

this is my js that calls the div and displays it as a dialog:

```
$.mobile.changePage('#answerResult',{transition:'slide', role:'dialog'});
```

and this is the div

```
<div data-role="page" id="answerResult" data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header" data-backbtn="false">
    <h1>Pop me up</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to create a timeout for the dialog so that it will autoclose after specified time?  I have searched google for this but I can't seem to find any answers that fits into what I want.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, after your line with `changePage`, add:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){ /* code to close dialog here */ }, 1000);
```

Here's the docs for [window.setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout)

Comment: Thanks for this.  this is what i did:
`window.setTimeout(function() {$('#answerResult').dialog('close')}, 1000);`
and it works.. Thanks !